# Spring boot java google app engine add kotlin error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, google-app-engine, kotlin

Im building a server using Spring boot with a mix of java and kotlin in eclipse IDE. I also use Google App Engine. It all works within eclipse with import and all that stuff but when i try to run or deploy to GAE it fails with the following exception.

**NOTE**: NotAcceptable Exception is in a Kotlin file that contains all exceptions of the system. Within the system its working but when i try to run it throws that. Any idea on how to solve this?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: pt/unl/fct/di/apdc/geotrails/utils/NotAcceptableException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindConstructorProvider.findConstructorBindingAnnotatedConstructor(ConfigurationPropertiesBindConstructorProvider.java:62) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindConstructorProvider.getBindConstructor(ConfigurationPropertiesBindConstructorProvider.java:48) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBean$BindMethod.forType(ConfigurationPropertiesBean.java:311) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeanDefinitionValidator.validate(ConfigurationPropertiesBeanDefinitionValidator.java:63) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeanDefinitionValidator.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationPropertiesBeanDefinitionValidator.java:45) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:286) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:174) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:152) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:132) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:92) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:145) [jetty-plus-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:64) [jetty-annotations-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72) [jetty-util-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:341) [jetty-servlet-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1445) [jetty-webapp-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1409) [jetty-webapp-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:825) [jetty-server-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:275) [jetty-servlet-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524) [jetty-webapp-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72) [jetty-util-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169) [jetty-util-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110) [jetty-util-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97) [jetty-server-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72) [jetty-util-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169) [jetty-util-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:407) [jetty-server-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110) [jetty-util-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97) [jetty-server-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:371) [jetty-server-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72) [jetty-util-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:367) [appengine-local-runtime.jar:na]
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:283) [appengine-local-runtime.jar:na]
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26) [appengine-local-runtime.jar:na]
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:87) [appengine-local-runtime.jar:na]
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:105) [appengine-local-runtime.jar:na]
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:271) [appengine-local-runtime.jar:na]
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:44) [appengine-local-runtime.jar:na]
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:220) [appengine-local-runtime.jar:na]
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:218) [appengine-local-runtime.jar:na]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_251]
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:218) [appengine-local-runtime.jar:na]
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:404) [appengine-tools-api.jar:na]
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:45) [appengine-tools-api.jar:na]
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:257) [appengine-tools-api.jar:na]
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:248) [appengine-tools-api.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pt.unl.fct.di.apdc.geotrails.utils.NotAcceptableException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:208) ~[na:na]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    ... 55 common frames omitted
```

appengine-web.xml:

```
<appengine-web-app
xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">

<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
<sessions-enabled>false</sessions-enabled>
<runtime>java8</runtime>

<system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file"
        value="WEB-INF/logging.properties" />
</system-properties>
<static-files>
    <include path="/**" />
</static-files>
<automatic-scaling>
    <target-cpu-utilization>0.9</target-cpu-utilization>
    <max-instances>30</max-instances>
    <min-instances>1</min-instances>
    <max-concurrent-requests>15</max-concurrent-requests>
    <max-idle-instances>2</max-idle-instances>
</automatic-scaling>
```

Comment: Apparently this file is not being created, can you share your structure on app engine after the deploy? Also, could you share your `.yaml` file? Are any other relevant details of your deploy you can share?

Comment: ill put the appengine-web.xml but i have no .yaml file

Comment: the file is following the exception. For some reason i couldnt make a divider